# VIM syntax coloring lua function name?

Tags: vim, lua, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm using VIM via terminal (SSH) and want to modify my syntax coloring settings in VIM to make the function_name Yellow for Lua programming. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to do that.

For example, in the code below - I want my VIM to syntax color `myFunc` yellow

```
local function myFunc(arg1)
    ...
end
```

I've been able to figure out how to make `function` yellow, by using this code below:

```
hi luaFunction ctermfg=Yellow
```

But this code does not color the word `myFunc` yellow (and frankly, I'd rather not syntax color `function` at all)

*Question*: Any ideas how I can syntax color the function_name in Lua?

Comment: The linked syntax file doesn't define anything for non-builin function names. You could try EasyTags or try to edit the syntax file.

Comment: romainl, what would I need to exactly add to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another (more complex) regex to match the function name.

```
:hi luaCustomFunction ctermfg=yellow
:syn match luaCustomFunction "\(\<function\>\)\@<=\s\+\S\+\s*(\@="
```

This uses a look-behind to match the word function. Then after 1 or more spaces it will highlight any word that has a parenthesis as the first non whitespace character after it.

This only highlights the function name. It does not highlight the parenthesis.

I think if you put these commands in `.vim/after/syntax/lua.vim` it should work.

The problem with putting them in your vimrc is that sometime after the vimrc is sourced the syntax highlighting file is sourced and generally the first line in there is `syn clear`. (Which wipes the custom syntax highlighting you just set)

Comment: FDinoff, this is perfect! One quick question, how do I make this syntax highlight work whenever I open a Lua file? When I put this into my .vimrc file, it doesn't seem to work. But if I type in those commands once I have vim open and viewing a Lua file, it then works. It'd be nice not to have to type in those commands ever time. Any ideas?

Comment: FDinoff, @FDinoff sorry, one more thing - I notice this doesn't work for `function abc.myfunc(` or `function abc:myfunc(`.  Basically, anything other than a space between the word 'function' and the name of the function, won't match. Can you up date this to work is those use cases? Thanks

Comment: @nickb Try the new one that is up there. I changed `\w` to `\S`. `\S` matches any non-whitespace character.

Answer (score 1):

This very naive implementation works with your sample:

```
:hi luaCustomFunction ctermfg=yellow
:syn match luaCustomFunction "\s\+\zs\S\+\ze("
```

It is obviously very limited but at least you get a starting point. Read `:h syntax` for further help.

Comment: romainl, this is matching anything before a paren, including more than function declarations. I only want to match function declaration and as such, I need a regex that matches "function ANYTHING(". How do I do that?  Also, do I put this script in .vimrc, because when I put it there it doesn't work

Comment: Also, this isn't matching when there is a space between the function_name and the "(".

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
hi def link luaFunction Function
hi Function ctermfg=Yellow
```